# Open rar. file with Opener app

Tags: rar

Trying to use opener app "Rar". Says it is 1-click. Rather, it toggles between Save to Folder and Zip/Unzip archive. Do not understand any of this, was looking for actual 1-click. Do I need a different app, or instructions on using this one?

Comment: Please add more information about your issue. What OS are you on? Provide a link to "opener app". Provide screenshots of "not 1-click" behaviour. Specify what do you mean under "1-click"? Have you tried using 7zip or WinRAR?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty confusing.  I would use 7zip for all my basic zip file needs.

use your right mouse button, click the file and then choose from the dialogue box what you want to do and then use your left mouse button to make it happen.  too easy.